How can I prevent a child component's linked stylesheet from overriding all styles in my React app?
I have a site created with React and Styled Components. I was given a new footer component by a different team, created in HTML, that I have to replace the current footer with. However, whenever I add this new footer, the styles being used in said file will override every other style it can across the entire app while it is rendered. If I remove it from a certain page, all is fine.
Is there a way I can prevent a <link> imported style from overriding all styles in my app? Or for the stylesheet to only affect the file it's imported to? It would be insanely frustrating to have to comb through every single component to see what has been overridden.

Welcome to SO! People usually expect a [mcve] to be included in a question, typically by sharing code that can be copy-pasted into an empty project to reproduce the issue. If you can edit your question to include that, it might be reopened.
